# capture user asked data from echo

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing a code for Amazon Alexa. And in the developer.amazon.com, we configure the intents, utterances etc... Here I need to get the question asked by the user.

I'm sure that this works using the intents but I will need the utterances. For eg:

```
GetTheData get me the user data
GetTheData get me user details
```

Here I'm able to get the `GetTheData` printed using `intent.getName()`, But i want to know if there is a way to get the content after the intent name i.e. ***get me the user data***. I want to know this for my research purpose.

Please let me know how can I get this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no way to get this information with the ASK/echo.

Your only solutions at this time would be to split that into one intent per utterance, or switch to google home (its SDK can give you the raw user text).

Comment: Thanks for that @Tom, even I did some research from my end and ended up with the same :-)